# HTML sticky navigation bar beneath a regular menu

Tags: html, css, menubar

I'm currently trying to implement a sticky navigation bar beneath my regular menu bar.

However, when I scroll up, my navigation bar covers my menu bar. Can someone help me there please? :)

```
*/ #navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
/* Navbar links */ #navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* Page content */ .content {
    padding: 16px;
}
/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */ .sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index:999;
}
/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */ .sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position:sticky.

```
.sticky {
   position:sticky;
}
```

See this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that without needing to use javascript at all. Here's what I did using html and inline css:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7b7972335d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: yellow;padding: 20px;">Menu bar</div>
    <div style="background-color: greenyellow;padding: 20px;position: sticky;top:0">Navigation bar</div>
    <div style="background-color: orange;padding: 20px;height: 100vh;">PAge body</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Except there's something specific you're trying to achieve, making the navbar sticky and setting the position to top should fix it

Comment: It's not quite working. If you run code snippet, you'll see when you scroll up, the regular menu still goes up and only nav bar stays sticky. OP needs menu and nav bar stays stacked and sticky when scrolling.